How to Prove $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n = F $
Question:
Let $ F $ be a compact subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ and define the sets
$$
V_n = \bigcup_{x \in F} \left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right).
$$
I need to prove that
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n = F.
$$
I understand that intuitively $ V_n $ represents "thickenings" of $ F $ that get smaller as $ n \to \infty $, so their intersection should "shrink down" to $ F $. However, I’m looking for a clear and rigorous proof of this.
Here is what I have so far:

Inclusion $ F \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n $: Since each $ V_n $ contains $ F $ by construction, it’s clear that $ F \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n $.

Inclusion $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n \subset F $: This part seems trickier. For any $ y \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n $, I know that there exists a point $ x_n \in F $ for each $ n $ such that $ y \in \left( x_n - \frac{1}{n}, x_n + \frac{1}{n} \right) $, which implies $ |y - x_n| < \frac{1}{n} $. Then $ x_n \to y $, and since $ F $ is compact, I believe this means $ y \in F $.


Could someone confirm if this approach is correct and, if not, provide a more rigorous argument for why $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n = F $ holds? Thank you for any help!

What is your definition of compact? Or do you have any theorems? Perhaps that a set is compact iff every open cover has a finite subcover?

What do you know about the distance from on exterior element to any element of. Your compact set?

Yes this is the definition, any hints on how to use it to show the equality

Correct me if I’m wrong but this intersection is just ${x}$.. no? And as you’re ranging over all $x\in F$ it becomes trivial.. or is THAT what you want to prove?

If $y \notin F$, where $F$ is compact, the distance $d(y, F) = \inf_{x \in F} |y - x|$ is strictly positive, and the infimum is attained because $F$ is compact. For large enough $n$, $y \notin V_n = \bigcup_{x \in F} \left( x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n} \right)$, as the intervals shrink below $d(y, F)$.
This proves that
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n = F,
$$
since $y \notin F$ implies $y \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n$, and $y \in F$ implies $y \in V_n$ for all $n$.

If $y \notin F$, then $W_n = \left \{ z \in \Bbb R \mid z \notin \left [y - \frac 1n, y + \frac 1n \right ] \right \}$ is an open cover of $F$ because $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} W_n = \Bbb R \setminus \{ y \}$.  Using the compactness of $F$, take a finite subcover from the $W_n$ (using the fact that $m \lt n \Rightarrow W_m \subseteq W_n$) to get the inclusion that you need.
Your approach works because $F$ compact $\Rightarrow F$ closed, which is what you need to see that the limit of a subsequence within $F$ also lies within $F$.  But the argument above is what you need to demonstrate that implication.

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! Appreciate it!

The question is a solution verification. You didn't answer the question being asked (if the given proof is OK).

Your proof is perfectly fine and works for every closed subset of a metric space. More generally, if $F$ is arbitrary, $\bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{x \in F} B_{1/n}(x) = \overline{F}$.
We don't need compactness. We don't need $\mathbb{R}$. That's just distraction.

Thank you lots for your feedback!
